# cannot parse Json properly usiing Firebase with Stripe

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

The error is -
Thread 7: "Could not parse the ephemeral key response following protocol STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider. Make sure your backend is sending the unmodified JSON of the ephemeral key to your app. For more info, see [https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard#prepare-your-api"](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard#prepare-your-api%22)

screenshot of the error is -
[image]
my MyAPIClient -

```
    import Stripe
       import UIKit
         class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.stripe.com")!

    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion)]
        var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data,
                let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            completion(json, nil)
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

viewcontroller code -

```
   import UIKit
   import Stripe
   import FirebaseFunctions

  class paymentViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var paymentMethodButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var proceedToCheckoutButton: UIButton!

var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupStripeConfig()
}

@IBAction func checkoutButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    paymentContext.requestPayment()
}

@IBAction func paymentMethodClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Payment Method Button Clicked")
    paymentContext.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
}

func setupStripeConfig() {
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
    config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
    config.requiredShippingAddressFields = .none

    let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient())
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .default())
    paymentContext.paymentAmount = 1000

    paymentContext.delegate = self
    paymentContext.hostViewController = self
     }
    }

   extension paymentViewController: STPPaymentContextDelegate {

  func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
    self.paymentMethodButton.titleLabel?.text = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption?.label
}


func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    //When stripeID isn't valid or Ephemeral key could not be retrieved for some reason. Handle this with UIAlert stating error and make user re-enter info
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {

    var data = [
        "customer":"Abhishek"
    ]
    //Pull Payment Method
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("getPaymentMethods").call(data) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Error \(String(describing: err))")
            return
        }

        print(result)
    }


       let idempotency = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        var paymentMethod = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption

    let dataToSend: [String : Any] = [
        "amount" : 5000,
        "customer" : "Abhishek",
    ]

       Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createPaymentIntent").call(dataToSend) { (result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Error \(String(describing: err))")
            return
           }

          //var paymentParam = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: result as! String)
        print(result)
       }
   }

  func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {

   }

  }
```

How to sort-it-out ?

Answer (score 0):

The request to create an Ephemeral Key has to be made server-side (with a secret key), and your iOS code should be making a request to your own server that in turn calls Stripe's API.

Right now, your code (in `MyApiClient`) is trying to directly call Stripe's API to create the Ephemeral Key client-side. This won't work, and if you log the request response or check your dashboard to see your recent requests you'll probably see some kind of error message.

You should take a look at Stripe's documentation for how to create the Ephemeral key [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#add-server-endpoint) - they walk through all the code and also have a glitch endpoint you can use for testing. Since your using Firebase, you can also check out the sample the have [here](https://github.com/stripe-samples/firebase-mobile-payments/tree/5cf9ab12c01576a8f5e3a654470467579cc2c014).